# How do I unit test unsubscribe in Angular and Jasmine?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, observable

I got private class members in my component, for example

`private querySubscription: Subscription;`.

In my `ngOnDestroy()` I unsubscribe from my subscription:

`ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.querySubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.userSettingsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }`

How do I test that I have really unsubscribed correctly in my unit test in jasmine? I can programmatically call the `ngOnDestory()` because it is public, but I can not test my private class members.

Comment: I believe that you need to somehow mock/spy upon place where you assign observable(or other) subscription to ``querySubscription`` and ``userSettingsSubscription`` and then replace(with spy?) ``unsubscribe`` method to know whenever it was called or not - but it's only an idea.

Answer (score 4):

You should mock your private variable (which you can access through array notation), then call your function, and expect the subscrpition to be closed.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-template-tsyupw?file=app/hello.component.spec.ts)

```js
  it('should unsubscribe on destroy', () => {
    component['querySubscription'] = of(true).subscribe();

    component.ngOnDestroy();

    expect(component['querySubscription'].closed).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

#### EDIT 1

This solution works because of array notation. In javascript, you don't have private or public variables : you only have variables.

Typescript forces you to comply with private/public, but you can always work around that.

If you wish not to do that, you should create a public function that creates a subscription like so

```
createSubscription() {
  this.querySubscription = this.someFunction().subscribe();
}
```

This is the only other viable solution if you don't want to use the array notation (which, I forgot to mention, is not a bad practice at all).

Up to you to choose which one you prefer !

Comment: This seems to work but when we change it to ``component.querySubscription = of(true).subscribe();`` compiler complains. I would be interested if this solution is proper one - maybe someone else has opinion on that?

Comment: @Buczkowski I have added an edit to my answer, feel free to check it out !

Comment: I do not want to make variables public, just for testing. This is bad practice in my opinion, because of several reasons. I do not want to access a private variable with a workaroung either, because typescript is giving me those for a reason. At the moment, I am leaning toward an implicit test.

Comment: I didn't tell you to make your variables public. Array notation isn't a workaround, it's a completely valid syntax used to dynamically get object properties. Private variables should already be implementation details. If you're not satisfied with any of the solutions, then you have a design flaw. You should try to make test driven development to avoid that. Finally, Typescript provides private and public properties for the developers as intellisense convenience, not as design patterns (because as said, JS doesn't have private or public properties).

Comment: That`s right, you did not tell me to make it public, but to make a public function for the subscription, which is also something I do not want to do. This should definitely not be the way to do it. The thing with accessing private variables can be discussed, but in general, you do want to test, what is usable from outside your components. It has a reason that it is private. Now I went for an implicit test, because there is no other viable solution as I see now. Typescript is definitely not only a better IntelliSense!

Comment: Well you'll have to if you don't want to use the array notation. And I personally don't think that you should test only what is accessible from outside of your component. By this logic, you could miss a lot of side effects in your dependency (but it's just my opinion, not the truth). And all solutions are "viable", but it seems they're not "suiting you" indeed. And I didn't say Typescript is a better intellisense, I said that variable accessors are an intellisense convenience in Typescript. And that is true (not my opinion this time). But good luck with your solution, keep me posted too !

Answer (score 1):

In my beforeEach I set the Subscription to a new instance of the rxjs class then I can spy directly on it.

```
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
....
let pagingSubscriptionSpy: jasmine.Spy;
beforeEach(() => {
 service.pagingSubscription = new Subscription();
 pagingSubscriptionSpy = spyOn(service.pagingSubscription, 'unsubscribe');
})
....
it('calls getEventunsubscribesPaged', () => {
   expect(pagingSubscriptionSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: pagingSubscription  is a private variable. So this cannot be accessed outside the class

Answer (score 0):

May be something like:

```
export class ObservableHelper {
    getMockObservable() {
        const s = new Subscription();
        const obs = new Observable();
        spyOn(obs, 'subscribe').and.returnValue(s);
        spyOn(s, 'unsubscribe');
        return {obs, s};
    }
}
```

in your spec file:

```
let helper = new ObservableHelper();
let o1 = helper.getMockObservable();
```

One of the comment it is already mentioned that Mock has to be done when a new subscription is created. If you are calling an external service and that returns an observable, o1.obs can be used as return value for same.

e.g. if you are subscribing for a PubSub service:

```
pubSubSpy.sub.withArgs(jasmine.any(Object), 'test').and.returnValue(o1.obs);


// Act
service.ngOnDestroy();

// Assert
expect(o1.s.unsubscribe).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Typescript and I suppose you are to test private members in your test module when setting up testBed you have to call your service using injector.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            YourService,
        ],
        imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
    });
    const injector = getTestBed();
    service = injector.get(YourService);
});
```

Now you can access your service public methods by using `service.myMethod` and your private ones by using `(service as any).privateMethod()`.

As typescript is always compiled to JavaScript and in JavaScript you do not have public private members you have to use the `(service as any)` construct.

**EDIT 1**

After you are able to access a private, you can access it's properties, so what you then do is (in pseudocode):

```
    spyOn((service as any).privateMethod, 'setBar');

    service.ngOnDestroy()

    expect((service as any).privateMethod.setBar).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Although the last part is right, your answer doesn't provide an answer to his problem.

Comment: Well it does I show him how to access private members from the test. If you know how to access a private member, then you can stub it, spy on it or do whatever you want. In our unit test we do it with no issue. With sinon you could do somethins as simple as const privateTest = spy((service as any).querySubscription, "unsubscribe"). Then assert if it has been called. With Jasmine I'm sure you can do something similar.

Comment: Yeah but this notion of using the injector to get a dependency instance can be found at the beginning of the unit testing guide. You didn't adapt it to his needs, nor you answered is answer on how he should mock it. I'ts just generic code.

Comment: Also, even though you can use that to get the dependence, it highly relies on your test implementation and if you used a test bed. Because it isn't stated in his question, you can't know if this answer is suited to his case.

Comment: He did not mentionf of using TestBed and it is commonly used in Angular testing like Jasmine. In our unit testing we do not use any of those, we use injector and Sinon + Chai and this implementation works with both. You suggested him to change his property to a public one, while I agree with you about TDD your solution is not suitable as well.

Comment: And his question is about testing a private, so I've shown how to access a private, then you can do with it whatever you want. You spyOn like I shown in one of the comments above, then call ngOnDestroy and then assert if the property unsubscribe has been called, that is all what is required in this case.

Comment: "Testbed is commonly used" doesn't mean "Test bed is always used". Again, I've never said he should set his variables public. My solution, contrary to yours, will work without an injector, which makes it viable ("suited" = opinionated), while yours isn't. And my solution is way cleaner than yours about accessing privates : while I only use an array notation, you get rid of typescript strong typing, which is indeed a bad practice.